# Array Index out of bounds - VBA Outlook

Tags: arrays, vba, indexing, outlook

I'm running across an error

> Array Index out of bounds

and not sure where to go from here as I've tried redefining the array.

I'm getting the error on the line: `Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders(folder)`

The error started to happen when I modified my code to also sort if the file had an attachment of not.

This was the original sorting code:

```
If InStr(UCase(Message.Body), "OUT OF THE OFFICE") Or InStr(UCase(Message.Body), "OUT OF OFFICE") Then
    folder = "Ignore"
ElseIf Message.Subject = "Secure Message Received" Then
    folder = "SecureMessageReceived"
ElseIf response = "YES" Then
    folder = "No changes"
ElseIf response = "NO" And newEmail <> "" Then
    folder = "ToBeLoaded"
ElseIf response = "NO" And newEmail = "" Then
    folder = "ToBeReviewed"
ElseIf response = "??" Then
    folder = "ToBeFixed"
End If
```

It was changed to this tidbit:

```
    If response = "NO" And iAttachments = 1 Then
        If newEmail <> "" Then
            folder = "ToBeLoaded"
        ElseIf newEmail = "" Then
            folder = "ToBeWorked"
        End If
    ElseIf response = "NO" And iAttachments = 0 Then
        If newEmail <> "" Then
            folder = "ToBeReviewed"
        ElseIf newEmail = "" Then
            folder = "ToBeReviewed"
        End If
    End If

    If InStr(UCase(Message.Body), "OUT OF THE OFFICE") Or InStr(UCase(Message.Body), "OUT OF OFFICE") Then
        folder = "Ignore"
    ElseIf Message.Subject = "Secure Message Received" Then
        folder = "SecureMessages"
    End If
```

The code will error here:

```
  Set SubFolder = inbox.Folders(folder)
```

And give me the 440 Array Index Out of Bounds error.

The FULL code for reference:

```
Dim objXLApp
Dim myRegExp

Function GetInbox(MailboxName As String)

Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder

Dim InboxFolder As folder
Dim MainFolder As folder
Dim SubFolder As folder


For Each MainFolder In Session.Folders
    If MainFolder.name = MailboxName Then
        For Each SubFolder In MainFolder.Folders
            If SubFolder.name = "Inbox" Then
                Set InboxFolder = SubFolder
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

Set GetInbox = InboxFolder 'objFolder
End Function

Public Sub ProcessAll_test()
Dim InboxFolder As folder
Dim Message
Dim MailboxName As String
Dim i
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "[a-z0-9\.\-\_]+\@[a-z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-z]+"

MailboxName = "test"
Set InboxFolder = GetInbox(MailboxName)
If Not InboxFolder Is Nothing Then
    Set emailList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    'For Each Message In InboxFolder.Items
    For i = InboxFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1 'Iterates from the end backwards
        Set Message = InboxFolder.Items(i)
        If TypeName(Message) = "MailItem" Then
            ProcessOne Message, InboxFolder
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub

Public Sub ProcessOne(Message, inbox)
Dim Pos, id, vals, name, email, response, attachment
Dim i
'Dim oMail As Object
Dim iAttachments As Integer

'Dim inbox As Object
'Set attachment = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Pos = InStr(Message.Body, "place X here:")

If Len(Message.Subject) > 0 Then
    vals = Split(Message.Subject, " ")
    id = vals(UBound(vals))
Else
    id = "No_Subject"
End If

name = Message.Sender.name
email = Message.Sender.Address
response = ""
newEmail = ""
RecDate = Message.ReceivedTime

'inbox = Folders("testfolder").Folders("Inbox")


If Pos > 0 Then
    x = UCase(Mid(Message.Body, Pos + 23, 20))
    Pos = InStr(x, "X")
    If Pos > 0 Then
        response = "YES"
    Else
        Pos = 1
        Do While Pos <> 0
            Pos = InStr(Pos + 1, Message.Body, "@")
            If Pos <> 0 Then
                posA = InStrRev(Message.Body, " ", Pos)
                posB = InStr(Pos, Message.Body, " ")
                emailSection = Mid(Message.Body, posA + 1, posB - posA - 1)
                anotherEmail = ""
                Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(emailSection)
                For Each myMatch In myMatches
                  anotherEmail = myMatch.Value
                Next
                If anotherEmail <> "test@test.com" Then
                    newEmail = anotherEmail
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        response = "NO"
    End If
Else
    response = "??"
End If

'Move email items
iAttachments = attachmentscount
'For i = iAttachments - 1 To 1 Step -1
'For i = 0 To iAttachments - 1
'If iAttachments = olMail Then
    If response = "NO" And iAttachments = 1 Then
        If newEmail <> "" Then
            folder = "ToBeLoaded"
        ElseIf newEmail = "" Then
            folder = "ToBeWorked"
        End If
    ElseIf response = "NO" And iAttachments = 0 Then
        If newEmail <> "" Then
            folder = "ToBeReviewed"
        ElseIf newEmail = "" Then
            folder = "ToBeReviewed"
        End If
    End If

    If InStr(UCase(Message.Body), "OUT OF THE OFFICE") Or InStr(UCase(Message.Body), "OUT OF OFFICE") Then
        folder = "Ignore"
    ElseIf Message.Subject = "Secure Message Received" Then
        folder = "SecureMessages"
    End If

WriteFile id, name, email, response, newEmail, RecDate, folder
Set SubFolder = inbox.Folders(folder)
'Next i

Message.UnRead = True
Message.Move SubFolder


End Sub

Sub WriteFile(id, name, email, response, newEmail, RecDate, folder)

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileName = fso.BuildPath(WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"), "test_" & Format(Date, "MMddyyyy") & ".xls")

Dim Content As String
' Create an excel object if there is not one already.
If objXLApp = Empty Then
    Set objXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End If

' Create or open existing file.
objXLApp.DisplayAlerts = False
If fso.FileExists(FileName) Then
    Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName)
Else
    Set objXLWb = objXLApp.Workbooks.Add()
End If
Set objXLWs = objXLWb.Worksheets(1)

' Add one row to the excel.
With objXLWs
    CurrentRow = 2
    While .Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Value <> ""
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Wend
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "ID"
    .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Name"
    .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Email"
    .Cells(1, 4).Value = "Response"
    .Cells(1, 5).Value = "New Email"
    .Cells(1, 6).Value = "RecDate"
    .Cells(1, 7).Value = "Folder"

    .Cells(CurrentRow, 1).Value = id
    .Cells(CurrentRow, 2).Value = name
    .Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Value = email
    .Cells(CurrentRow, 4).Value = response
    .Cells(CurrentRow, 5).Value = newEmail
    .Cells(CurrentRow, 6).Value = RecDate
    .Cells(CurrentRow, 7).Value = folder
End With

objXLWb.SaveAs FileName, True
objXLWb.Close
End Sub
```

---

In particular, I will get the error at this section of the code:

```
iAttachments = attachmentscount
'For i = iAttachments - 1 To 1 Step -1
'For i = 0 To iAttachments - 1
'If iAttachments = olMail Then
    If response = "NO" And iAttachments = 1 Then
        If newEmail <> "" Then
            folder = "ToBeLoaded"
        ElseIf newEmail = "" Then
            folder = "ToBeWorked"
        End If
    ElseIf response = "NO" And iAttachments = 0 Then
        If newEmail <> "" Then
            folder = "ToBeReviewed"
        ElseIf newEmail = "" Then
            folder = "ToBeReviewed"
        End If
    End If

    If InStr(UCase(Message.Body), "OUT OF THE OFFICE") Or InStr(UCase(Message.Body), "OUT OF OFFICE") Then
        folder = "Ignore"
    ElseIf Message.Subject = "Secure Message Received" Then
        folder = "SecureMessages"
    End If

WriteFile id, name, email, response, newEmail, RecDate, folder
Set SubFolder = inbox.Folders(folder)
'Next i

Message.UnRead = True
Message.Move SubFolder


End Sub
```

Comment: Inbox is never defined.  You need to declare a variable for Inbox and then set the correct object to it. : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getdefaultfolder-method-outlook

Comment: What's the value of `folder` when it blows up? Is it empty? If not, does that folder exist? If so, that's the `response` value and can you change your nested conditionals to ensure `folder` has a legit existing value before you get the `subFolder`? If not, can you just `Exit Sub`? We can't guess what you're trying to do. But that error means `folder` doesn't exist in the `Folders` collection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Put Option Explicit at the top of the module. Declare all variables. Fix typos. Remove code that is not necessary to the question. If you do not remove the WriteFile line then add the associated code.

Comment: You test `newEmail` but I cannot see where it is given a value other than `""`.The code to give a value to `folder` uses If-Then-ElseIf-EndIf so it will not always be given a value.  Not having a value will give an Out-of-bounds errior.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. I reposted the full code and have tried some of your suggestions in reference to my old code.

Answer (score 0):

The Array Index out of bounds error was not recreated.

With the following you may be able to pin down or fix your error.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ProcessOne_test()

    Dim inbx As folder
    Dim mItm As mailItem

    Set inbx = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set mItm = ActiveInspector.currentItem

    ProcessOne mItm, inbx

End Sub

Public Sub ProcessOne(Message, Inbox)

    Dim Pos, id, vals, name, email, response, attachment
    Dim iAttachments As Integer
    Dim i

    Dim newEmail As String
    Dim recdate As Date
    Dim folder As String
    Dim subFolder As folder

    Pos = InStr(Message.body, "please place an X here:")

    If Len(Message.subject) > 0 Then
        vals = Split(Message.subject, " ")
        id = vals(UBound(vals))
    Else
        id = "No_Subject"
    End If

    name = Message.sender.name
    email = Message.sender.Address

    response = ""
    newEmail = ""
    recdate = Message.ReceivedTime

    'iAttachments = AttachmentCount
    iAttachments = Message.Attachments.count

    'Move email items

    For i = 1 To iAttachments - 1
    ' Appears irrelevant
    Next i

    If iAttachments >= 1 Then

        If response = "NO" And newEmail <> "" Then
            folder = "ToBeLoaded"
        'ElseIf reponse = "NO" And newEmail = "" Then
        ElseIf response = "NO" And newEmail = "" Then
            folder = "ToBeWorked"
        End If

    ElseIf iAttachments = 0 Then

        'If reponse = "No" And newEmail <> "" Then
        If response = "No" And newEmail <> "" Then
            folder = "ToBeReviewed"
        'ElseIf reponse = "NO" And newEmail = "" Then
        ElseIf response = "NO" And newEmail = "" Then
            folder = "ToBeReviewed"
        End If

    End If

    If InStr(UCase(Message.body), "OUT OF THE OFFICE") Or InStr(UCase(Message.body), "OUT OF OFFICE") Then
        folder = "Ignore"
    ElseIf Message.subject = "Secure Message Received" Then
        folder = "SecureMessages"
    End If

    'WriteFile id, name, email, response, newEmail, recdate, folder

    If folder <> "" Then

        On Error Resume Next
        Set subFolder = Inbox.folders(folder)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If subFolder Is Nothing Then

            MsgBox "Subfolder " & folder & " not directly under " & Inbox.name & "." & _
              vbCr & vbCr & "Message not moved."

        Else

            Message.unread = True
            Message.move subFolder

            MsgBox "Message moved to " & folder & "."

        End If

    Else

        MsgBox "No folder assigned. Message not moved."

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I've ran this and have a general idea on where my error is. With running your code. It'll go about 5 messages in before stopping altogether.

I think it's at the Message.Move part where my script is bugging out... Hm

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so thanks to everyone's suggestions. I got it.

It was basically giving a command to folders and what to do with the messages.

I used nitron's code and modified it slightly, but that seemed to do the trick.

So below the WriteFile line, I added this:

```
If folder <> "" Then

    On Error Resume Next
    Set subFolder = Inbox.Folders(folder)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If subFolder Is Nothing Then

        Message.UnRead = True
        Message.Move subFolder

    Else

        Message.UnRead = True
        Message.Move subFolder

    End If

End If
```

While it seems redundant to have the Message.Unread and Move twice, it seems to kick it off.

Comment: You cannot move items to "Nothing". If you continue to work on this, put Option Explicit at the top of the module. There is a setting in the editor to do this automatically on new modules. Put a value in attachmentscount or directly in iAttachments. Probably `Message.Attachments.count`.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely an error associated with not having the Outlook Object Library linked in the Macro. (I had the same Array Index Out of Bounds Error for a different project).

Enable this through Tools -> References -> Tick "Microsoft Outlook X.0 Object Library" and press OK.